# how to enable mobile browser in jitsi-meet with api

Tags: javascript, jitsi, jitsi-meet

can anyone help me with this, how to enable chrome browser use for jitsi meet on android and ios with jitsi meet api

i set disableDeepLinking: true and MOBILE_APP_PROMO: false but it doesnt work.
thank you !

```
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js"></script>
<div id="meet"></div>     
<script>
var domain = 'meet.jit.si';
var options = {
   roomName: 'tester',
   ConfigOverwrite: {
        disableDeepLinking: true,
    },
    interfaceConfigOverwrite: {
       MOBILE_APP_PROMO: false,
    },
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet')
};

var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```

Comment: ConfigOverwrite should be configOverwrite camel case

Answer (score 1):

now it works, but only with adroid handys and tablets, on ios devices i got camera and microphone error.

you have to change a jitsi server file and restart jitsi with /etc/init.d/jitsi-videobridge2 restart

change in /usr/share/jitsi-meet/libs/app.bundle.min.js

from:
function i(){return"android"===r.a.OS||“ios”===r.a.OS}

to:
function i(){return false; return"android"===r.a.OS||“ios”===r.a.OS}

Tip:
To easily find the part of code search for:

return"android"===